# .NET Core dependency injection - many databases, one DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have an ASP.NET Core application using the DI from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. The app connects to a stupid number of databases with an exact same interface, let's say a 100 of them. I want to facade them all with the same DbContext, say `ExternalDbContext`. The only difference between them is the connection string they're using. I need to instantiate the correct version of the context for a given request. So the chain of resolution would go like this:

1. User makes a request that has a `provider = 'ABCD'` parameter.
2. This is mapped to an Action in a Controller which has an `ISomeService` as a dependency.
3. That service has a method `DoStuff(string provider)`.
4. Here's the crucial part. The `ISomeService` needs a dependency on the data layer, but this cannot be a hard dependency on one injected `ExternalDbContext`, since that has to be resolved dynamically. My idea is to have an `IExternalDbContextFactory` which in turn can take an `IServiceProvider`. That factory would have a method `GetExternalDbContext(string provider)` and I would resolve the correct `ExternalDbContext` using the injected service provider.

To achieve that I would have to register the `ExternalDbContexts` in a way that would allow me to resolve them from an `IServiceProvider` based on a string parameter. For obvious reasons I don't want to have a 100 different useless marker classes inheriting from `ExternalDbContext` and then register them independently. Also I would prefer to use the handy `AddDbContext` method somehow.

I obviously could build my own resolution infrastructure entirely, but I'd rather reuse an existing solution than spend days writing and testing boilerplate for this particular use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage connection strings using overload of `AddDbContext` which provides you access to [`IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContext__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_System_IServiceProvider_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder__Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ExternalDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
        {
             var connectionString = serviceProvider.GetService // get service 
             // which can determine connection string
             .GetConnectionString();
              options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
         });
       }
}
```

For example you can resolve `IHttpContextAccessor` there and check the request parameter.

Comment: This would work I guess, but I'd be interested to see a way that doesn't rely on accessing the current http context. What if my frontend wasn't a web app, for example? This would directly tie the business layer of the system into the ASP layer.

Comment: @V0ldek no it should not directly tie the business layer, cause this is handled in the DI. Also you can introduce interface `IConnectionStringProvider` which will encapsulate all needed logic and inject corresponding implementation during registration.