# Run and access multiple instances of a DI-service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

i'm creating an REST application which needs to access different databases on different servers. Therefore, during installation, you can specifiy which servers you want to access and enter connection details for each server. These information get stored in a configuration file.

During startup i setup a DI-service which handles the database access using the information from the config file. Now i am kinda lost. I don't really now how to proceed. I am thinking about running multiple instances of the database access service but how do i specify which one to use? And how do i setup my controllers? I need to be able to choose the instance of the service i want to access with each REST request.

I'm happy about every suggestion.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412065/net-core-dependency-injection-many-databases-one-dbcontext/62412231#62412231) answer can help you?

Comment: Your question is very broad. Try to be more specific by showing what code you have. A MVCE might be valuable.